# What is the viscous force acting on a cube?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity

I'm aware of the viscous drag formulae to calculate the drag force acting on a moving sphere inside a viscous fluid. But how do you improve the formulae to get the force acting on a cube with side length a?

Comment: I am not sure a cube can be described similar to a sphere. The problem may be that there is always a scale on which the corners and edges of the cube cause turbulence, which is not the case for a sphere in a viscous liquid. That's just a hunch, and I am looking forward to a real answer by somebody who knows.

Comment: I get the feeling if I equal the volume of the cube to a sphere with equal volume and hence obtain it's radius i will be able to put it directly into the stroke's equation. But as u mentioned if the corners cause a turbulance that is not possible!

Comment: If you look at the drag coefficient for very high Reynolds numbers (fully developed turbulence), then the cube (frontal flow) has a drag coefficient of 1.05, while a rough sphere is 0.47 or so. A smooth sphere is much smaller (cited as low as 0.1!)... so it seems really dependent on how the turbulence forms around the body. I am still trying to find a publication that has a diagram with the drag coefficient as a function of Reynolds number. You have really triggered my interest in how flow develops around a cube.

Comment: Let me know if you find one. :)

Comment: Will certainly do.